# C copy file with memcpy and mmap file to RAM

Tags: c, io, mmap, memcpy

I have file1.txt

```
This is my file
```

and file2.txt

```
This is my second file
```

and I want copy file2.txt content to file1.txt using `memcpy`

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
    int d;
    int d2;
    int p;
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    if(argc == 3){
        f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
        f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
            d = da_open(argv[1]);
            d2 = da_open2(argv[2]);
            p = da_cp(f2, f1, 10); 
            da_map(d, 10);
            da_map(d2, 10);

            close(p);
            //closef(d2);
    }
```

}
I don't know why but when I run this I get file2.txt with lots of random symbols. Why? what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
my full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

int da_open(const char *name);
int da_open2(const char *name);
void *da_map(int d, int size);
int da_cp(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n);

int da_open(const char *name){
   int dskr;
   dskr = open( name, O_RDONLY, 0640 );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
      perror( name );
      exit( 255 );
   }
   printf( "dskr = %d\n", dskr );
   return dskr;
}

int da_open2(const char *name){
   int dskr;
   dskr = open( name, O_RDWR, 0640 );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
      perror( name );
      exit( 255 );
   }
   printf( "dskr = %d\n", dskr );
   return dskr;
}

void *da_map(int d, int size){
   void *a = NULL;
   a = mmap( NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, d, 0 );
   if( a == MAP_FAILED ){
      perror( "mmap failed" );
      abort();
   }
   return a;
}

int da_cp(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n){
         memcpy(str1, str2, n);
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
        int d;
        int d2;
        int p;
        FILE *f1;
        FILE *f2;
        if(argc == 3){
            f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
            f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
                d = da_open(argv[1]);
                d2 = da_open2(argv[2]);
                 p = da_cp(f2, f1, 10);
                da_map(d, 10);
                da_map(d2, 10);

                close(p);
                //closef(d2);
        }
}
```

Comment: What's `da_open` and `da_open2`?

Comment: `memcpy` copies memory, not "files". Your OS may have a C function for it.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` doesn't work over a file descriptor, you can store the content of file1 in an array of chars (using `fgets` or `fread`) and then copy to file2 (using `fputs` or `fwrite`)

Also note that you need to use `fclose()` instead of `close()` with `fopen()`

Answer (score 2):

`d` and `d2` are  not files, they're just file descriptors (something that stores the information about the file and its input/output states).

If you want to copy from 1 file to another, you have to read the first file first. That's the example of how you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Open the first text file
FILE *f = fopen("textfile1.txt", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

// Read it into buffer
char *buffer = malloc(fsize + 1);
fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
fclose(f);

buffer[fsize] = 0;

// Now write the string buffer into your second text file
FILE *f2 = fopen ("textfile2", "wb");
fwrite (buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f2);
fclose (f2);
```

So, as you see, the `memcpy` can only perform with memory in RAM and it has nothing to do with files in hard drive (unless you read it into your RAM memory)